# ADB command-line app installation [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT] error

Tags: android, adb, apk

I built and signed my apk with command line commands and I want to install it with adb install command but I got the following error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
```

When I searched this error, I found the solutions for android studio and eclipse development environment, but I want to know how I can fix it from command line as I built and sign my app from command line?